# Applescript Variable issue

Tags: shell, variables, applescript

I am having issues with this script when run it errors out

```
tell application "Finder"
    set music_file to some file of the folder "Macintosh HD:ringtones"
end tell
set volume output volume 30
do shell script "afplay '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/ringtones/'" & music_file
```

this is the error:
**do shell script "afplay '/Volumes/Macintosh HD/ringtones/'Macintosh HD:ringtones:Zen_ag_NARITA_HI_long_1.mp3"
        --> error "may only specify one file to play**
so I attempted to use a posix command such as:

**set conver to POSIX file of music_file**

and that errors out

What I cannot figure out is why the music_file is getting the whole HFS path in it when I tell it to just get the file and how to correct for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set myFolder to "/Users/me/Desktop/test"
tell application "System Events" to set music_file to POSIX path of (some file of folder myFolder)
set volume output volume 30
do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of music_file
```

Comment: We have a winner, I thank you both for your input on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript is weird. `music_file` is of type `document file` as defined by the `Finder` app, instead of being some other kind of `file` object. If you convert it to an `alias` with `music_file as alias`, then you can get the `POSIX path` of it which is what’s needed on the command line. Finally you need to wrap another set of `'` characters around the filename in case it includes spaces. Note that this will break if the filename itself contains `'` characters, as in `Crazy 'Cause I Believe.mp3`.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set music_file to some file of the folder "ref:Users:andrew:Music:iTunes:iTunes Media:Ringtones"
end tell
set volume output volume 30
do shell script "afplay '" & (POSIX path of (music_file as alias)) & "'"
```

Comment: this is a good start, what I want to do is just grab that random file name from music_file which is what I thought I was asking the Finder for. Then I can do a **shell script "afplay 'Macintosh HD/music/'"& music_file**
without worrying about spaces in the filename.